# How do I make a motor spin every 10 minutes?

Tags: motor

I am new to Arduino, please don't be harsh. I want to make a motor spin at every x amount of time (Lets say 10 minutes). Once the program is started, I want it to start the motor (stop after 10 seconds), and every 10 minutes, it continues the process. Is it possible to make it?,

Comment: Yes, possible and a good start for a beginner. Look into the BlinkWithoutDelay example. Try some tutorials about `millis()`. That will give you the understanding about how you can do timed things with an Arduino. If you have any specific problems with that, you can always come back here and ask about it :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to use `delay()` to implement the waits:

```cpp
void loop() {
    turn_motor_on();
    delay(10000);  // 10 seconds
    turn_motor_off();
    delay(600000);  // 10 minutes
}
```

Since these long numbers may be difficult to read, you can make them
more readable by defining some units:

```cpp
const unsigned long second = 1000;
const unsigned long minute = 60000;
```

Then you can for example `delay(10 * minute);`

Beware there is a trap if you try to do arithmetics with integer
literals. The following:

```cpp
delay(10 * 60 * 1000);  // BUG!
```

will **not** work on most Arduinos, as the multiplications will be
performed on the `int` data type, which can only hold numbers up to
32,767. It is safer to use either explicitly typed constants (`unsigned long` is the appropriate type for delays) or integer literals typed with
the suffix `UL` (which stands for “unsigned long”).

Note that the Arduino will do no useful work while delaying. If you want
to do any kind of work during the delay, see the “Blink Without Delay”
Arduino example.

Comment: Dude! Teaching a newbie to use delay? That path leads quickly to madness! (To the OP: It's fine until you want to check for a button press, read a sensor, or do **anything else** during that delay. The Arduino comes to a screeching halt in a delay.)

Comment: I would advise learning to use `millis()` to accomplish the same thing, right away. If you use `delay()` you will only end up having to rewrite your code later.

Comment: @DuncanC: Yes, when a beginner is at level 0, I think starting with the simplest possible approach is better. And `delay()` is simpler than `millis()`: that's why Blink is in section 1 of the Arduino examples while BlinkWithoutDelay is in section 2. Also “having to rewrite your code later” is actually a good thing for a beginner. That's how you learn! But note that I warned the OP that he may have to use the BlinkWithoutDelay approach at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it's possible.  The loop() function might look something like:

```
loop(){
    turn_motor_on();
    wait_seconds(10);
    turn_motor_off();
    wait_minutes(10);
}
```

Now all you have to do is write your turn_motor_on() and off functions and also wait_seconds() and wait_minutes().  I'll leave the motor controls to you since you have not provided any detail on how the motor is hooked up.

You could use the Arduino delay() function:

```
void wait_seconds(int num_seconds){
    for(int i=0; i<num_seconds; i++){
        delay(1000);
    }
}

void wait_minutes(int num_minutes){
    for(int i=0; i<num_minutes; i++){
        delay_seconds(60);
    }
}
```

Of course there are many other ways to do this but this method is simple and easy to understand and will get you started easily.